# SweetAlert html option not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert

Sweet alert with html option is not working can you guys explain me to solve this.or otherwise i want to bind template explicitly to sweet alert.

```
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: '<b>Hiiii</b>' ,
        type: "info",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#F44336",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, accept it!",
        closeOnConfirm: true
        html:true
    }, function() {
        $scope.onComment(record);
    });
```

Can you people help me to solve this sweet alert problem?

Comment: please add some codes, what have you tried so far?

Comment: As @lin said, provide code. And you can use AngularJS SweetAlert wrapper https://github.com/oitozero/ngSweetAlert

Comment: swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: '<b>Hiiii</b>' ,
            type: "info",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#F44336",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, accept it!",
            closeOnConfirm: true
            html:true
        }, function() {
            $scope.onComment(record);
        });

Answer (score 1):

as Doc says :

```
html is no longer used. Instead use the content object.
```

(https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)

try:

```
swal({
  content: "input",
});
```

Comment: I have installed through bower

Comment: double check the path you included (is the dist folder?)

Comment: swall is working fine but with html true option is not working.

Comment: actually i want to show dynamic html table in swall.

Comment: are you using a template inline or a url?

Comment: swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            template: '/views/public/access.html' ,
            type: "info",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#F44336",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, accept it!",
            closeOnConfirm: true
            html:true
        }, function() {
            $scope.onComment(record);
        });

Comment: use the dit of the response

Comment: swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: '<th>user</th><th>Reason</th><th>Date</th>'+'\n'+'<tr ng-repeat="info in rejectedInfo"><td>'+info.user+'</td><td>'+info.reason+'</td><td>'+info.rejDate+'</td></tr>' ,
            type: "info",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#F44336",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, accept it!",
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            html:true
        }, function() {
            $scope.onComment(record);
        });

Comment: Can you please tell me to bind html dynamic table to swall with url basis or inline.

Comment: html is no longer used. Instead use the content object. as doc says https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Comment: if it helped you ..rate it .. so for other people they know it is corretc :)

Comment: I want to show the dynamic message(html) in swall too.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it in the new Version.
Please see the information below.

[sweet-alert display HTML code in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838965/sweet-alert-display-html-code-in-text/49401430#49401430)